# Bootstrap carousel caption and indicator outside

Tags: jquery, html, css

iam using bootstrap carousel on my site. I need caption and indicator on right side. i did it but when iam clicking on indicator the caption and indicator is not changing. please help me.

Here is my [Link](http://urips.co.in/glue-test/apps-pharmacy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your javascript file and try

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

and also include `bootstrap.js`

Hope this may helpful

Comment: hi jake, thats already added i need the text to be changed with image on click of indicator.

Answer (score 0):

When using the standard carousel markup you can simply change the indicator's and caption's position with overriding its CSS

```
.carousel-caption {
    right: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators {
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```